# Не нашелся с ответом

Tags: фразеология

Иногда попадается выражение "не нашелся с ответом", но кажется, что звучит довольно коряво. Не подскажете, есть ли такое устойчивое сочетание?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что віражение следует признать допустимым. По крайне мере - на разговорном уровне.

Прямо в таком виде оно в словарях мне не попадалось, но можно вывести из двух соображений.
Во-первых, у слова "найтись" есть подходящее значение ("сообразить", "не растеряться") - http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C&all=x.
И во-вторых, конструкция "с чем" вполне может означать объект действия в формах наподобие "поторопись с ответом".

Соединяя первое со вторым получим требуемое. И вот пример, подтверждающий это (единичный, к сожалению, из авторитетных).

> Изведут, отдалят, ― произнес он, глянув в сторону и как бы видя вдали
>   некие таинственные и другим непонятные откровения, ― ну что,
>   полагаешь, нужно мне, чего еще искать? Попов не нашелся с ответом. ―
>   Чего желать человеку в моей судьбе? ― продолжал князь, не поднимая
>   лица. [Г. П. Данилевский. Потемкин на Дунае (1876)]

(из нацкорпуса)